# Swagger question: How to set request example for IList type using Swashbucklet.AspnetCore for xml documentation?

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I am trying to set examples for RestApis in swagger. I am using Swashbuckle.AspnetCore package. For string or int types, they work well by adding an example attribute to the param, or add annotation but somehow it doesnt work when the param type is an IList.

For example, this works:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the Name
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>Joe Smith</example>
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

but this doesnt show the example:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the list of Toys.
        /// </summary>
        /// <example>['Tiger']</example>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "toys", Required = Required.Always)]
        [Required]
        public IList<string> Toys { get; set; }
```

Anyone shed some light please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use double quotes, this should work

```
/// <example>["test","test2"]</example>
```

Comment: Thanks. I finally  found my problem - I was using version 5.x where this is only supported on 6.x! Doh!